# TYPO3: show title attribute for protected email address

Tags: email, title, typo3

I have here a TYPO3 v. 4.3.2 and I see that a inserted link to an e-Mail address has no title attribute despite it is set in RTE with

> Opens window for sending email

I only see something like this

```
<a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('nbblubp+jtestoevt/bu');">info(at)test.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box. In my installation, links are generated like this:

```
<a class="mail" title="Opens window for sending email" href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('ocknvq,htcig/vtkhhv/cpvyqtvBuyt0fg');">info(at)test.com</a>
```

In other words:

- Check your TypoScript config (around `config.spamProtectEmailAddresses`)
- Check your rtehtmlarea version (and update if outdated)
- Consider updating to [4.3.13](http://sourceforge.net/projects/typo3/files/TYPO3%20Source%20and%20Dummy/TYPO3%204.3.13/) or, even better, to 4.5 (LTS)